# Is there an argument that can be made the BASIC is a higher level language than Javascript?

Tags: javascript, basic, high-level

I'm taking an introduction to IT course at WGU.  According to the quiz results I got, Javascript is not a high level language while BASIC is a high level language.  Not Visual Basic, not Quick Basic, classic BASIC is a higher level language than Javascript.  Can anyone rationalize this?  Humor would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This question is basic

Comment: I don't agree with them at all. High-level languages are essentially everything above Assembly.

Comment: This question isn't really appropriate for [so], it might be more appropriate for [cs.se].

Comment: I guess you should read Module 15 page 93 to see what their rationale is for this answer.

Comment: I think it's a trick question. Javascript isn't a language; JavaScript is.

Comment: And if I had to rank these 4 languages on how high they are, I would agree with your answer. The original Dartmouth BASIC (which I actually used when I was a teenager) had much simpler data and control structures than any of the other languages. Just numbers, arrays, and strings, no heterogeneous structures. Subroutines didn't take parameters, functions could only be one line, and all variables are global.

Comment: I read Module 15 page 93.  This is what it said, "There is a large number of high-level languages used to write programs.  Some of the most common being: BASIC, C, C++, Java, and Python."  No rationale is given.  My theory is the writer did not include Javascript in the list so the person who wrote the quiz decided it was not a high level language.

Comment: Now that I think of it, the idea that BASIC is commonly used to write programs is hilarious.

Comment: I guess the fact that there are more compile-to-JS languages than compile-to-BASIC languages could be confused for an argument if you squint really hard.

Comment: Asad, that's a good rationalization.  It's like Javascript is the machine language of the web, if you ignore webassembly.

Comment: Maybe is something about compilation. And maybe the author of the question misses his [MSX HotBit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotbit).